# Need help coming up with query to find something that is in everything

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

Ok, I am working with the publishers database and the query that I need to come up with
is **to find the title of any book that has sold copies in every store.**

The main tables that I am dealing with are `title`, `sales` and `store`

Here is my attempt

```
  SELECT title, titles.title_id, stores.stor_id, sales.stor_id, stor_name
    from titles
     FULL OUTER JOIN sales on sales.title_id = titles.title_id
    FULL OUTER JOIN stores on stores.stor_id = sales.stor_id
    --WHERE sales.stor_id = stores.stor_id AND sales.title_id = titles.title_id
```

I have an idea what I should do. I need to join `titles.title_id` to `sales.title_id` annd then check to see if `sales.stor_name` is  equal to `stores.stor_name`

Comment: Severely lacking detail -- table, columns, what you've tried?

Comment: The reason why I didnt put alot of detail is because I thought someone would have been familiar with the publisher database and they would have known the tables and keys. I edited my response with a little bit more detail

Comment: Where I come from, it's the [parts and suppliers database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppliers_and_Parts_database) and the task is to find [suppliers who supply all parts](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm). Follow the `relational-algebra` tag to find similar questions and links to useful articles such as [this one](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/research/divpresentation.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.title from titles t1
where t1.title_id not in (
  select sub.title_id from sales sa
  right join (
    select t.title_id, stor_id from titles t, stores st
  ) Sub on sa.title_id = sub.title_id and sa.stor_id = sub.stor_id
  where sa.title_id is null)
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/718ef/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.title_id, t.title
from titles as t
where (select count(*) from stores) 
    = (select count(distinct store_id) from sales where title_id=t.title_id)
```

Comment: When I try to run this I get invalid column name stor_id. I think the reason is because you are not including stor_id in the second part of the where clause

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using "IN" in mysql.. Your question seems to be lacking in detail but from what i understand, you need to use the "IN" function

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/03/25/mysql-in-query-performance/

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look something like:

```
select titles
  from title, sales, store
 where (join conditions here)
```

The join conditions should be what relate the title and store table as well as the store to sales table.  For example, if my title table had a ISBN field and my store table had an ISBN field, you should include `title.isbn = store.isbn`.  You will need to include an `and` for all join conditions.